# Django map permissions

Tags: geoserver, wms, django, administration

I want to build a site using Django and have a user authentication system. In that site I want to serve maps and other data, but not to all users.

What I am interested in is: can I give the maps some viewing permissions? I could build maps with Geoserver and OpenLayers, I just don't know how to serve them for each user.

Expected behavior: Have some maps (WMS, GeoJson features etc.) and a user with some permissions. Logged in he should see a few of those maps (as for his permissions). If he logs out he shouldn't see the map (by visiting a url or something similar). If his permissions are revoked he can no longer see maps.

Can this be done using Django and Geoserver (or other map service solution)? What should I start learning?

Comment: Hi. I hope you found answers because I am facing exactly the same problem : I have a PostGIS database with data (GIS layers) I want to publish to the web but with a user control (checking who is allowed to see what, but also logging who sees what). I would like to do that with Django has it offers "out-of-the-box" many features I need.
Have you succeeded ?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question, specially for @DarthKangooroo comment.

It's been a long time and I've moved away from GIS since then. I am now just a basic web developer. I can't remember well my scenario back then but from the experience I accumulated over the years:

- Django is a backend framework, it stands between the browser and whatever data sources we have (database, Geosever API, static files etc).
- you will have to learn how to use it but Django is great for beginners as it comes with functionality including users, administrators, authentication and permissions.

That's a generalization but it's true. You will need to follow a basic Django tutorial and in end you will be able to create:

- users with authentication and permissions
- views(pages) that use Geoserver data and have restrictions (ex: only for logged in users, only for 'admin' users etc).

I did a quick google search and it looks like Django is well adopted by the GIS community. good luck!